# How to run tests without closing webdriver using PO?

Tags: java, selenium, testng

Please help me with my Selenium project.
Link for GIT repository: https://kodov@bitbucket.org/kodov/addressbook5.git

I have an application Addressbook ( https://sourceforge.net/projects/php-addressbook/ ) which I want to test.
I made several tests for Login page and page for creating a new contact.
The case is to make:

1. Negative test for login
2. Positive test for login
3. Then I don't need to close the browser but to run tests for creating a contact.
   The problem is that I made POM and my tests and pages are in different classes, so I don't know how to quit the
   Webdriver just after all tests, but not after the first one.
   Maybe I need to change annotations.

Comment: So if I understand correctly there are two problems:
1. Your browser is closing after every test.
2. You want to close/quit the browser once all the tests are completed.
correct me if I am wrong?

And cases 1,2 and 3 is a single test?

Comment: Actually, it closes after every test class. You are right, I want to quit the browser after all tests are completed.

Comment: Can you make your git repo public if possible?

Comment: Yes, sure.     https://bitbucket.org/kodov/addressbook5/src/master/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Base Test class and make the other tests class extend that class.

For example:

```
public class BaseTest {

public static WebDriver driver;
private static boolean isTestsStarted;
public static WebDriverWait wait;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        // To run setup method before all tests that extends this base class
        if(!isTestsStarted) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ConfProperties.getProperty("chromedriver_path"));
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        driver.get(ConfProperties.getProperty("base_url"));
        isTestsStarted = true;
}
    }

    // To quit driver after all tests run
    // This will run only once, after all tests ran
    // Another advantage of this is, it will quit driver even though you stop the program manually
    static {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
            driver.quit();
        }));
    }

}
```

Then extend this base class in your test classes
for your loginTest class

```
public class LoginTest extends BaseTest {

    public static LoginPage loginPage;
    public static MainPage mainPage;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        // You can call driver object since you initialized it in your parent class
        loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
        mainPage = new MainPage(driver);
        driver.get(ConfProperties.getProperty("base_url"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testUserCanNotLoginWithInvalidCredentials() {
        loginPage.clearUsernameField().clearPasswordField()
                 .enterUsername(ConfProperties.getProperty("invalid_username"))
                 .enterPassword(ConfProperties.getProperty("invalid_password"))
                 .clickLoginButton();
        assertThat(loginPage.getLoginButton().isDisplayed()).isTrue();
    }

    @Test
    public void testUserCanLoginWithValidCredentials() {
        loginPage.clearUsernameField().clearPasswordField()
                 .enterUsername(ConfProperties.getProperty("valid_username"))
                 .enterPassword(ConfProperties.getProperty("valid_password"))
                 .clickLoginButton();
        assertThat(mainPage.getUserName())
                 .isEqualTo(ConfProperties.getProperty("valid_username"));
    }
}
```

With the same way, you can use your driver object in other classes if you make those classes extend BaseTest class

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. I made changes in the project, but can't make it use the same driver and session. The problem is that I want my first test class open the browser and after that the second test class open that browser and use it. I made new branch with my revisions. https://bitbucket.org/kodov/addressbook5/src/master/

Comment: It doesn't work because In your first class (CreateNewAddressTest) you use driver.quit() method with @AfterClass annotation. and you initialize new driver in LoginTest class. What happened when you tried the approach that I suggested?

Comment: Yes. It worked! Sorry for my inadvertence. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to **login** no matter what, so you have to include the login part in both of your tests.

You can also try `@Test(dependsOnMethods = { "testName" })` but I am not sure not if this works when your test is in another file.

Comment: I want to login one time and then continue testing in this session. And after all tests to logout.

Comment: YOu can add the login part in your @beforeClass method.

Comment: If I do that, then how to make a positive login test? Because if I login beforeClass, it is two ways - if I can login or not and they are not in @Test, but in beforeClass.

Comment: Have a test which will login n do the rest of the stuff.